# Creating a binary, repeating, optical signal

Tags: binary, signals, repeat

I've got around 100 individual LEDs that need to be identifiable.  They are all the same color, but I can make each one blink on and off with whatever pattern I want.  The limitation is in the camera that detects these lights.  It operates at 30 fps, so I am limited to 15Hz signals.  I have confirmed that I can detect 15 Hz signals pretty reliably.

The lights must continually repeat their individual blinking patterns so that the camera can detect them very shortly after they enter the camera's field of view.  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on what sort of signals would allow me to do this with as few bits as possible.

With a 7 bit identification number I can create 128 individual signals, but I'd have to add a header/checksum in order for them to be distinguishable.  For instance, continually repeating "0101010" would be indistinguishable from continually repeating "1010101."